# Error installing sunspot_solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I resolve this issue. Installing sunspot_solr gem in rails app.

```
 > gem install sunspot_solr -v '2.1.1'
ERROR:  Error installing sunspot_solr:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /home/prabhakar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/sunspot_solr-2.1.1.gem
```

Comment: Try this `rm -f /home/prabhakar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/cache/sunspot_solr-2.1.1.gem` then `gem install sunspot_solr -v 2.1.1`

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install
`gem install sunspot_solr -v 2.1.1`